# MarkLogic SEC-NOADMIN error

Tags: security, admin, marklogic

I had a dev MarkLogic instance that was working yesterday.  Today, I tried to deploy, and received an error during the deploy process.  I then tried to go visit the MarkLogic server on localhost:8001, and I get the following error.

```
500: Internal Server Error
SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin role.
In /MarkLogic/security.xqy on line 4845
In sec:check-admin()
In /lib/status-check.xqy on line 15
In status-check()
In / on line 6
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged in as the same user as yesterday? Access to all of the admin interface on port 8001 is limited to users with the admin role.

Comment: I was, yes.  But... how could I switch users if the entire site simply gives that error?

Comment: @MrA I've seen that error when the security DB or one of its forests was missing or corrupted. Did you deploy involve changes to that?

Comment: @MrA Also, since Marklogic uses HTTP auth to determine the user, you can change it by using whatever means your browser supports (usually putting the username (and optionally, password) followed by @ in the url, like so: `http://user[:password]@server.domain.com`